# SQL Server aggregation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called `EventLog` like this:

[EventLog Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLopg.png)

I would like to display  the count of each event type for each `deviceId` like so:

[Aggregated Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fHV.png)

Then, ultimately, show only devices where the type3 count and type4 counts differ:

[Different Counts Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9LXv.png)

I know I will need to use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` and possibly a nested `SELECT`?

I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    deviceId, 
    MIN(eventType) AS [Type3], 
    MAX(eventType) AS [Type4]
FROM 
    EventLog
WHERE 
    eventType IN (3,4)
GROUP BY 
    deviceId;
```

But that just returns the minimum and maximum value for each `deviceID` instead of counting the occurrences of type 3 and type 4 `eventTypes`.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to split the `eventType` values into their own columns.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT deviceId, COUNT(eventType)
FROM eventLog
WHERE eventType = 3
GROUP BY deviceId;
```

But that (obviously) only returns the count per deviceId for eventType 3 - and I need a column for eventType 3 AND one for eventType4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum the cases in your select and filter in the having where those sums don't match.

```
SELECT 
    deviceId, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN eventType = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type3Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN eventType = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type4Count
FROM 
    eventLog
WHERE 
    eventType IN(3,4)
GROUP BY 
    deviceId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN eventType = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> SUM(CASE WHEN eventType = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```